# converting months numbers to days

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a .npz file that I have read data from and converted to a table in a .txt file.
[image: table]

the data comes with a month associated to each value. I have to convert these numbers to the written month ( January = 1, Febuary = 2, etc.) using a dictionary.

However when I do this the table changes to list just december
[image: changes to list just december]

My code:

```
import numpy as np

outfile = ("heathrow_weather.npz")

#find out names of arrays
ph_read= np.load(outfile)
print(ph_read.files)

#assign arrays to a variable
max_temp=ph_read['t_max']

month_no=ph_read['month']

year_no=ph_read['year']

rainfall=ph_read['rainfall']

min_temp=ph_read['t_min']


#working marks

MonthDict={ 1 : "January",
       2 : "February",
       3 : "March",
       4 : "April",
       5 : "May",
       6 : "June",
       7 : "July",
       8 : "August",
       9 : "September",
       10 : "October",
       11 : "November",
       12 : "December"
}


for i in month_no:
    month_no = MonthDict[i]

#print(month_no) produces only "december"

outfile = open("weather_tables.txt", "w")
outfile.write("Month    Year    Min Temp    Max Temp    Rainfall\n")
outfile.write("                   (°C)         (°C)         (mm)\n")


for t0, t1, t2, t3, t4 in zip(month_no, year_no, max_temp, min_temp, rainfall):

    string = str(t0)+"      "+str(t1)+"        "+str(t2)+"          "+str(t3)+"         "+str(t4)+"\n"
    outfile.write(string)

outfile.close()
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this really need an *image* of your output?

Comment: Month_no is just a string...your value of it is written 12 times in the loop...so it's the last one

Comment: I wasn't sure how to format a table input in my post and wanted to show how the file was being changed

Comment: Use datetime library and look at strptime and strftime. -1 for pictures instead of data.

Comment: Use Code Formatting for such tables in your post.

Comment: Oh, so use 4 spaces then text with spaces for formatting? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for i in month_no` loop is simply overwriting `month_no` each time through the loop, not creating a list of all the month names corresponding to the ones in the original `month_no` array. Use a list comprehension.

```
month_no = [monthDict[i] for i in month_no]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Still wrapping my head round list comprehension for my course(however dumb that sounds)